# XPath: count the number items in each level of a list

Tags: xml, xpath

I have some XML lists, nested in multiple levels (lists, with sub-lists, sub-sub-lists, and so on). I need a way of determining (using XPath 1.0) the largest number of  elements grouped together at each level in the list.

For example, if I had the following:

```
<list>
    <list-item><p>List item 1</p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>List item 2</p>
        <list>
            <list-item><p>Sub-list item 1</p></list-item>
            <list-item><p>Sub-list item 2</p></list-item>
        </list>
    </list-item>
    <list-item><p>List item 3</p>
        <list>
            <list-item><p>Sub-list item 1</p>
                <list>
                    <list-item><p>Sub-sub-list item 1</p></list-item>
                </list>
            </list-item>
            <list-item><p>Sub-list item 2</p>
                <list>
                    <list-item><p>Sub-sub-list item 1</p></list-item>
                    <list-item><p>Sub-sub-list item 2</p></list-item>
                </list>
            </list-item>
            <list-item><p>Sub-list item 3</p>
                <list>
                    <list-item><p>Sub-sub-list item 1</p></list-item>
                    <list-item><p>Sub-sub-list item 2</p></list-item>
                    <list-item><p>Sub-sub-list item 3</p></list-item>
                </list>
            </list-item>
        </list>
    </list-item>
    <list-item><p>List item 4</p></list-item>
</list>
```

In this I would need to determine the largest number of grouped  elements at each level. So in the above example I would find:

- Level 1 (i.e. list items): 4 elements
- Level 2 (i.e. sub-list items): 2 elements
- Level 3 (i.e. sub-sub-list items): 3 elements

I hope that makes sense.

I'm using a typesetting package that can use XPath 1.0. It doesn't do 2.0 unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: For the top level list I could just count the list-items and that was simple enough. For the second level I counted the list-items in each second level <list> and used my typesetting software's scripting functions to pass the largest of the count values to a variable.

It was when I got to the third level that I got stuck. To be honest, I wasn't doing the second level in an efficient way to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will be able to do this in XPath 1.0, also not if sending one query per level.

You'd have to find all lists of a given level (which is easy: `//list[count(ancestor-or-self::list) = $level]`), and then compare its count to the count of *each other* list on that level. This would require applying `count(...)` to each of those lists, which is not possible in XPath 1.0. The *XPath 2.0* query allowing to do this would be something like

```
//list[
  count(ancestor-or-self::list) = $level and
  not(count(list-item) < //list[count(ancestor-or-self::list) = $level]/count(list-item))
]
```

where the last "axis step" `./count(list-item))` is what you will not be able to do in XPath 1.0.

You might be able to fetch all lists of a given level and search for the maximum outside XPath.

Comment: Isn't `fn:count` XPath 1.0? i would say so, according to the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count

Comment: it is, but applying functions in axis steps isn't.